# AngularJS Multiselect dropdown hide not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have implemented directive to handle multi select dropdown.

I want to dismiss the dropdown once we click anywhere in the document except the mulitselect button  itself. Here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
<label class="col-md-2 control-label">Search Fields:</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <button class="btn form-control" id="multiSelect" ng-click="toggleMultiSelect()">
            <span class="pull-left">-- Select a search field -- </span>
            <span class="pull-right">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
    </button>   
    <div class="dropdownOptions col-md-12" ng-show="isMultiSelectVisible">
        <div ng-repeat="cfg in fieldList | orderBy:'label'" class="dropdownOption">
            <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" 
                            ng-model="cB[cfg.name]"
                            ng-click="addFields(cfg)">
                    <span class="mL5">{{cfg.label}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                                          
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app');
app.directive('dynamicView', ['$http', 'HttpService', 'Toastr', '$log', '$document',
    function($http, HttpService, Toastr, $log, $document) {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'app/directives/dynamic-view.directive.html',
            scope: {
                config: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element) {                    

                scope.isMultiSelectVisible = false;

                scope.toggleMultiSelect = function(){
                    scope.isMultiSelectVisible = !scope.isMultiSelectVisible;
                }

                element.on('click', function(event) {
                    console.log("Buton Click");
                    event.stopPropagation();      
                });

                $document.on('click', function(){
                    console.log("Other Click");
                    scope.isMultiSelectVisible = false;
                    scope.$apply();
                });

            }
        }
    }
]);
})();
```

Issue here is either I click on button or any where in the document I get in console "Buton Clicked".

So both the events are not getting fired respectively.

Comment: You didn't post all the code, so it's hard to guess in this way. But you bind the first click on `element` which is the `dynamic-view` directive. Most probably your `dynamic-view` fills all the body. Using then `event.stopPropagation();` the second click on the `document` doesn't get fired

Comment: Yes @quirimmo:  dynamic-view does fill the whole body . How can I bind click to dynamic view ?

Comment: so the explanation is above. If you want this behavior remove `event.stopPropagation()` from the first event and you should see also the second `click` logged

Comment: But how will I be able to differentiate between button and rest of the directive area ?

Comment: passing in the `click` function the `$event` and checking `$event.currentTarget` which will hold the reference to the current target. But again, if your directive fills all the body, your `$document` is filled totally with your directive, so you can't click on the `$document` without clicking on the directive